# Solidity pass object to params?

Tags: solidity

I have a function that calls methods of other contracts, and depending on the type, the parameters for methods should be different.

Is there a way in Solidity to pass something like an object in which different types of parameters can be?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I can do this with call and encodeABI()